# PCL working with shared code (cross platform library)

Tags: android, sockets, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm new with Xamarin and have to create a cross platform library (iOS, Android, Win Phone). i have so much difficult to create a pcl who works for those 3 platforms.
For example, this pcl needs establish a socket connection with a printer.
In pcl i can't use System.Net.Sockets so my idea is create a method and tried call his code with shared project . 
when i execute the code, is stepped over the code inside `#if __ANDROID__ .`

PCL

```
public class Class1
{
    public void socket()
    {
        Conecta.Class oi = new Conecta.Class();
        oi.conecta();
    }
}
```

Shared code

```
#if __ANDROID__
using System.Net.Sockets;
#endif


namespace Conecta
{
    class Class 
    {
        public void conecta()
        {
#if __ANDROID__

        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        clientSocket.Connect("192.168.210.171", 4002);
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("teste \n");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

#endif
        }

    }
}
```

It's just a test, the code isn't sophisticated
Someone can help me? 
Any other idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe PCL is not yet finished. 
Even if you can resolve your printer issue in future you will have a lot of other problems.

In our project we prefer to share a code from one directory with different .csproj files.

PCL benefits really not worth powder and shot.

Comment: I have problems with shared code because with him, i can't generate a DLL or something like this. right? I will need to export the code with security and i don't know how do this with shared code.  ideas?

Comment: You need to export one dll for all projects? With shared code it can't be done. But #if _ANDROID_ won't be work with PCL too. If you really want it to be crossplatform, you'll need to figure out how to use platform independent API. But I think you don't need that pain. Is there some reason to stick to the separate DLL file?

Comment: Yes. My job is develop library for mobile communication with printers that my enterprise sells. With xamarin we wanna publish a cross-platform library for this communication. This is why i can't show the code and the idea was just one dll. But now this seems impossible with xamarin :(